# inserting into database is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

am using XAMPP , and PHP Version 5.4.27 , and writing a code of a simple form that inserts the data in the field to the database of my localhost

I created the database using `XAMPP Control Panel` and the name of the database is `sitedb`

and created a table : `customers`

Columns are :

[image: columns]

**Here is my php code:**

```
    <html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$conSet = mysql_select_db("sitedb",$con);

  $users_name = $_GET['name'];
  $users_email = $_GET['email'];
  $users_tele = $_GET['tele'];
  $users_age = $_GET['age'];

  $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
  $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
  $users_tele = mysql_real_escape_string($users_tele);
  $users_age = mysql_real_escape_string($users_age);

$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sitedb`.`customers`(`CustomerID`,`Full Name`,`Age`,`E-mail`,`Tele Phone`) VALUES (NULL,'$users_name','$users_age','$users_email','$users_tele')",$con);

  mysql_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML code of the form:**

```
    <html>
<body>

<form action="addCustomer.php" method="get">
Full Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
TelePhone: <input type="text" name="tele"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I enter the html file through `localhost` and fill in the fiels of the form and click submit button , no errors appear , but the data wasn't inserted

why?

Comment: Im not a php programmer, but to be sure, are you executing the actual statement? Looks like `$res` is not executed?

Comment: You're not checking your calls to `mysql_*()` for errors so you won't see any. Check the value of `mysql_error()` after your query.

Comment: do your error reporting on if it is off. Again stop using mysql_* as its deprecated,instead use mysqli_*. Again check if there is any primary key constraint in database table.

Comment: is `age` primary and unique? seems like it from the image. could be a prob

Comment: Put error_reporting(E_ALL) on top of your php code and look if now an error gets reported

Comment: Sidenote: you are susceptible to SQL injection and you shouldn't by using `mysql_*()` for new code - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The customerID can not be null. So trie this query:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sitedb`.`customers`(`Full Name`,`Age`,`E-mail`,`Tele Phone`) VALUES ('$users_name','$users_age','$users_email','$users_tele')",$con);
```

Also you should check for errors.

Comment: Did it , first data added (CustomerID = 0 ) , second time , didn't , why?

Comment: @GabourX is it your primary key? change the definition to `auto_increment`

Comment: Look at the picture , i don't why the primary key icon is yellow on the `Age` column , and how do i set `auto_increment`

Comment: So you can add the auto_increment to your table: ' ALTER TABLE customers Identifier int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: ` Alter TABLE customers drop primary key` and `Alter TABLE customers add primary key (CustomerID)` So you can change the primary key to the id column.

Comment: I can't see any way to change the primary key or to set it

Comment: Who has created the column? Are you connected as `root` user to your db?

Comment: i droped both `CustomerID` and `Age` columns , and then created them again , when i was creating `CustomerID` there was a ListBox field named `index` , i set it as a primary key , and saved ! , but still the yellow icon appears on the `age` column ! why?

Comment: I don't know. Works your program?

Comment: even when i try to create a new table , it just doesn't set the right primary key

Answer (score 0):

Yes Customer ID have a primary key so that customer id take automaticaly value and is auto incremented. So no need to define customer id... that cause error is sql query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$conSet = mysql_select_db("sitedb",$con);

$users_name = $_GET['name'];
$users_email = $_GET['email'];
$users_tele = $_GET['tele'];
$users_age = $_GET['age'];

$users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
$users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
$users_tele = mysql_real_escape_string($users_tele);
$users_age = mysql_real_escape_string($users_age);

$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sitedb`.`customers`(`CustomerID`,`Full Name`,`Age`,`E-  mail`,`Tele Phone`) VALUES      ('".$users_name."','".$users_age."','".$users_email."','$".users_tele."')",$con);

mysql_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

when u calling values from db try to do with this :-

```
VALUES('".$users_name."','".$users_age."','".$users_email."','$".users_tele."')",$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo mysql error (if any) after execute query. Try following code to get proper mysql error.

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sitedb`.`customers`(`Full Name`,`Age`,`E-mail`,`Tele Phone`) VALUES ('$users_name','$users_age','$users_email','$users_tele')",$con);

if (mysql_errno()) {
   echo "Mysql error : "mysql_errno($con) . "- " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
   exit;
} 
  mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

First put these lines before the mysql connect ->

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and then submit the form and most probably the problem will be in your query.and write down this query->

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `sitedb`.`customers`(`Full Name`,`Age`,`E-mail`,`Tele Phone`) VALUES ('".$users_name. "', '" .$users_age. "', '" .$users_email. "', '" .$users_tele."')";
$res = mysql_query($insert_query);
```

once you have any problem in the query then echo your `$insert_query` variable and then copy that query and run it directly into your xampp phpmyadmin panel.